# newby mode solidify outline issue

Tags: modeling, node-editor, outliner, emission

im trying to make a simple lil model thats just flat and has outlines to learn about it
so all parts work
except the hair

how do I fix it?

[image: the hair outline of solidify fills up half of his head]